# HTML Button Alignment to be made in right of row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to take both the buttons to right side of the row. As you can see in the screenshot (both are left)

I tried different ways including float-right but it wasn't properly styling it.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-2" style='text-align: right;'>
          <button style='width: 100% !important;' 
            class='btn btn-theme'>VAT Details</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <button style='width: 100% !important;' 
            class='btn btn-theme'>NCIIC</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: share minimal reproducible code

Comment: its Bootstrap right? try the classe: "d-flex flex-row justify-content-end" for the row-div

Comment: @Warden330 yes it is!! Thanks, it worked :)

Comment: You can just add "row justify-content-end" since row is display flex by default.

Comment: Siona ,You could also just use "d-flex justify-content-end since flex is row by default. But i recommend using all of the classes cause it helps to understand WHY its working, also @GrayFox25 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/ You can find the explanations in that part of the documentation

Comment: You guys are amazing, thanks!!

Comment: @Warden330 ," But I recommend using all of the classes cause it helps to understand WHY its working" this can help beginners understand what's going on but I wouldn't recommend it.  It's a bad practice to add code where it's not needed as it increases the code size and affects the page load.

Comment: @SionaFernandes thats only partially true. Whats "default" and if its working depends entirely on the Browser you use. So there can be cases where it is NOT enough to leave out. Also we are here to make People Understand things not just solve issues. But yes it is important to make them aware that unecessary Code is bad practice, that i agree on definetly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
<div class="row justify-content-end">
        <div class="col-2" style='text-align: right;'>
          <button style='width: 100% !important;' 
            class='btn btn-theme'>VAT Details</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <button style='width: 100% !important;' 
            class='btn btn-theme'>NCIIC</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Since row is display flex by default you just need to add `justify-content-end` to the row.